# specific syntax question

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is it possible to create template to the initialization like:

```
template <typename C> typename C::value_type  fooFunction(C& c) {...};
std::vector<string> vec_instance;
fooFunction(cont<0>(vec_instance));
fooFunction(cont<1>(vec_instance));
```

In general i'm interested is it possible to specify template using integer (ie. 0) instead of true type name.
And how to achieve above?

Comment: If the container template has a non-type template argument, yes, but I'm not sure that that is what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hmm, what would be the non-type argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but the following snippet works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename C>
typename C::value_type  fooFunction(const C & c) { return 0; };
/* note that fooFunction takes a ref-to-const, not a reference  */ 

template<int N>
struct cont
{
public:
   typedef int value_type;
   cont(vector<string> vec) {};
};

int main()
{
std::vector<string> vec_instance;
fooFunction(cont<0>(vec_instance));
fooFunction(cont<1>(vec_instance));
}
```

Two changes worth noting:

1. An integer is not a type, so if cont is declared `template <typename T>`, what you have written will not work.  `template <int N>` is the proper way to parameterize over an integral value, as templatetypedef mentioned.
2. I'm not sure how `cont<>` is defined, but from your usage it must be an object you are constructing as a temporary.  You will have trouble passing this temporary as a reference into `fooFunction`.  Note that my example above passes C as reference-to-const instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parameterize templates over non-type arguments like integers, pointers, and other templates.  For example:

```
template <typename T, int N> struct Array {
    T data[N];

    /* ... other functions ... */
};
```

These templates work just like all the other templates you've seen, except that they're parameterized over integral values rather than types.

[This link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_106.html) has some more info on the subject.  "Modern C++ Design" and "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" also have lots of info on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? Non-type template parameters:

```
template<int n> class Cont
{
public:
    typedef int value_type;
};

template<>
class Cont<0>
{
public:
        typedef double value_type;
        value_type convert(const std::string& s) const
        {
            return atof(s.c_str());
        }
};

template<>
class Cont<1>
{
public:
        typedef long value_type;
        value_type convert(const std::string& s) const
        {
            return atoi(s.c_str());
        }
};

template <int n> typename Cont<n>::value_type  fooFunction(const Cont<n>& cont, const std::string& s)
{
    return cont.convert(s);
}
void test()
{
    Cont<0> c0;
    Cont<1> c1;
    double d = fooFunction(c0,"1.0");
    int i = fooFunction(c1, "-17");
}
```